# Error with getline ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

The error I am getting is "no matching function call to getline(const char*&, String*&)". I am trying to get a line out of a text file, an example of one of the lines is: 4:17,Dark Alliance. The reason i need to use getline is because after i get the line i need to chop it into 2 parts based on the comma(delimiter) in between the song length and the title. Any help is appreciated thanks. Here is the code:

```
  String* song_line = new String;
  song_line = getline(file_name, song_line); //here is where the error is coming in.

  Tokens* song_token = new Tokens;
  char delimiter = ",";
  song_token = createTokens(song_line, delimiter);

  String* length = getToken(song_token, 0);
  String* song_title = getToken(song_token, 1);
  addSong(cd, song_title, length);
```

Comment: Please don't use pointers.

Comment: @KerrekSB the way the assignment is structured and the parameters the functions take require me to. I wish i didn't have to.

Comment: unless the assignment specifically tells you to use pointers, _please don't use pointers_.

Comment: @MooingDuck it does. The professor gave us all the function declarations and parameters so i'm afraid i have to.

Comment: @user3558697: Just because a function takes pointers as parameters doesn't mean you have to dynamically allocate memory.

Answer (score 3):

`std::getline` takes a `istream` for it's first parameter, not a `char*`.  Additionally, the second parameter is a `std::string&`, not a `std::string*`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline